# events in SAP Spartacus 4.0, subscribe from service

Tags: angular

I am trying to regsiter an event in Spartacus

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CartDetailsComponent, PromotionService} from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { ActiveCartService, SelectiveCartService, AuthService, RoutingService, CartActions} from '@spartacus/core';

import { EventService } from '@spartacus/core';
import { ProductDetailsPageModule } from '@spartacus/storefront';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {

  constructor( activeCartService: ActiveCartService,  eventService: EventService) { 

    this.eventService.get(CartActions).subscribe(console.log);

  }


}
```

I am getting this error

Date: 2022-07-31T13:26:44.830Z - Hash: b09036d1398327199bc7
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 48.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 290ms
: Compiled successfully.

```
ERROR in src/app/components/myservice.service.ts:16:22 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof import("/sparta0/node_modules/@spartacus/core/src/cart/store/actions/cart-group.actions")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<unknown>'.
  Type 'typeof import("/sparta0/node_modules/@spartacus/core/src/cart/store/actions/cart-group.actions")' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<unknown>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.

16     eventService.get(CartActions).subscribe(event => console.log(event));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have read https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/2.x/event-service/
and watched https://microlearning.opensap.com/media/Event+System+-+Spartacus+-+SAP+Commerce+Cloud/0_h3j4ihzm/178318381

but in neither case can I make this working.
I am injecting this service into a component which is extening a spartacus cms component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had not imported the correct event...

Import { LoginEvent, ProductActions } from '@spartacus/core';

```
  //this.eventService.get(CartAddEntryEvent).subscribe(event => {});
  //this.eventService.get(LoginEvent).subscribe(event => {});
```